# spring-cloud-config: spring-cloud-config maven config error

Tags: maven, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I try to write an spring cloud config server example.My maven's pom config

```
<parent>
    <groupId>cn.bcolor</groupId>
    <artifactId>bcolor-parent-pom</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<groupId>cn.bcolor</groupId>
<artifactId>bcolor-config-center</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

In the `bcolor-parent-pom`

```
     <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>Edgware.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
```

When I run the program，The exception is as follows

`org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointAutoConfiguration': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$29caa1fa]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'configServerHealthIndicator' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/config/server/config/EnvironmentRepositoryConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'configServerHealthIndicator' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cloud.config.server.config.CompositeConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setEnvironmentRepos' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cloud.config.server.config.DefaultRepositoryConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'transportConfigCallback'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'propertiesBasedSshTransportCallback' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/config/server/config/TransportConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.eclipse.jgit.api.TransportConfigCallback]: Factory method 'propertiesBasedSshTransportCallback' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean.forExecutables()Ljavax/validation/executable/ExecutableValidator;`

I configure it according to the example of the official website. In addition to this pom file

Please help me, thank you！

Comment: Sounds like you have mixed versions of spring dependencies

Comment: You can see with mvn -X dependency:tree

Answer (score 0):

Did your pom have spring.verion property like this:

```
<properties>
  <spring.version>4.3.8.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>
```

You will get an error if you use spring.verion property, spring-boot-maven-plugin and Spring Config together while running 'mvn spring-boot:run' command.

---

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.8.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project without-parent: An exception occurred while running. null: InvocationTargetException: Error creating bean with name 'propertiesBasedSshTransportCallback' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/config/server/config/TransportConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.eclipse.jgit.api.TransportConfigCallback]: Factory method 'propertiesBasedSshTransportCallback' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean.forExecutables()Ljavax/validation/executable/ExecutableValidator; -> [Help 1]